# using timespec struct in multimap, where and/or how to define operator<

Tags: c++, struct, multimap

I've got some inherited code that went something like this.  (Please hold the laughter... I KNOW this is ugly even after I've pseudo-codified it. That's why I'm trying to improve it and my first thing to work on is the bone headed (by my way of thinking) storing of time as a double of milliseconds since the epoch, and using that time as the key in the multimap).  Anyway this is the "before" code, call it foo.h:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

#include "yasper.h"
using yasper::ptr;

class foo
{
private:
    ...
public:
    foo(...);
    virtual ~foo();
    ...
bool operator() (const ptr<foo> poFoo1, const ptr<foo> poFoo2)
    {
        ...
    }
}
...
typedef ptr<foo> fooPtr;

typedef queue<fooPtr> fooQueue;
typedef list<fooPtr> fooList;
typedef fooList *fooListPtr;

typedef multimap<double, fooPtr> fooTimeMap;
```

I also know that my platform doesn't provide time precision anywhere near nanoseconds but it is a little better than seconds or milliseconds.  Also I've tried to understand and implement the suggestions from several similar question both from google results and from this site ( [C++ Using .find() with struct as key in map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655179/c-using-find-with-struct-as-key-in-map)   and   [using struct as key in map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124640/using-struct-as-key-in-map)  ).  However those are slightly different because they are for their own new struct and I am trying to do it with an existing standard library struct.

So my main goal is to change that last line to:

```
typedef multimap<timespec, fooPtr> fooTimeMap;
```

When I make only that change, I get

In member function 'bool std::less<_Ty>::operator()(const _Ty&, const _Ty&) const [with _Ty = timespec]':
/.../include/cpp/xtree:895:   instantiated from 'std::_Tree<_Traits>::iterator std::_Tree<_Traits>::find(const typename _Traits::key_type&) [with _Traits = std::_Tmap_traits, std::less, std::allocator > >, true>]'
/home/.../foo.cpp:109:   instantiated from here
/.../include/cpp/functional:136: error: no match for 'operator<' in '_Left < _Right'

Based on these and other referenced posts, I've tried to define the less than operator for timespec...  e.g. before the closing } of class foo, I put

```
bool operator() (const timespec& lhs, const timespec& rhs)
{
    return ( lhs.tv_nsec < rhs.tv_nsec && lhs.tv_sec == rhs.tv_sec ) ||
        lhs.tv_sec < rhs.tv_sec;
}
```

but I guess I don't understand where is the right place to do that and why.  Or even if it is not "the right place" but somewhere that is valid enough to make the `multimap<timespec,...>` compile (and run : - ).  Also some posts talk about defining operator<(...) and others talk about operator()(...).

I'd rather not define a whole new wrapper class like timespec_compare_class around timespec (I've seen the syntax of `multimap<timespec, fooPtr, timespec_compare_class>` in other posts) so I'd rather avoid that if there is a way to do it within class foo itself, or even after the } of foo but still within foo.h.

(note, I don't think the "bool operator() (const ptr poFoo1, const ptr poFoo2)", nor the fooQueue, fooList, nor fooListPtr are relevant to the question but I've left them in the pseudo-code just in case.)

So, aside from "read a C++ primer", which I know I need to do, can anyone point me at a slightly quicker solution?

@thb and @MarkRansom, thanks for replying... yeah those were mentioned in other posts too though as I said slightly different cases like with their own new structs, which I tried to apply to my case.

e.g. 1) When I do `bool operator() (const timespec& lhs, const timespec& rhs)` inside the { braces } of foo, I still get "error: no match for 'operator<' in '_Left < _Right'"

e.g. 2) when I do that outside the braces, just before the typedef multimap, I get "bool operator()(const timespec&, const timespec&)' must be a nonstatic member function".

e.g. 3) When I do `bool operator< (const timespec& lhs, const timespec& rhs)` inside the braces, I get "'bool foo::operator<(const timespec&, const timespec&)' must take exactly one argument"  And even if I changed that to one argument, I don't think that's what I want because I'm not trying to tell it how to compare a foo to a timespec.

e.g. 4) When I do that outside the braces, just before the typedef multimap, I get "multiple definition of `operator<(timespec const&, timespec const&)'".

So are one of these closer to the right track, or something completely different?

Comment: Is there a reason that you prefer not to rename *operator()* to *operator<* ?  At any rate, I know of two basic ways to do what you want.  First, by *operator<.*  Second, alternately, by defining a suitable *Less* functor.  (In my experience, the first usually seems easier.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change it slightly more:

```
struct TimeTest
{
    bool operator()(timespec const& lhs, timespec const& rhs) const
    {
         return <TEST>
    }
};
typedef multimap<timespec, fooPtr, TimeTest> fooTimeMap;
```

The reason that I would take the extra step is that if you define operator< for timespec is that it has a high chance for a clash with any C++ library that uses time information. They may not define the same ordering and then things get complicated.

By explicitly setting the comparison you guarantee there will be no clashes.

Comment: Three cheers for the kindness of strangers!!  This compiles (with the following outside the "class foo { ... }").  Thank you VERY much!

struct TimeTest
{
 bool operator()(const timespec& lhs, const timespec& rhs) const
 {
  return ( lhs.tv_nsec < rhs.tv_nsec && lhs.tv_sec == rhs.tv_sec ) || lhs.tv_sec < rhs.tv_sec;
 };
};
typedef multimap<timespec, fooPtr, TimeTest> fooTimeMap;

Comment: I should say, this compiles, and I will report back if it does not also test well! : - )

Answer (score 1):

Why not define the less-than operator as

```
bool operator< (const timespec& lhs, const timespec& rhs) { ... }
```

which differs slightly from what you wrote?  The function-call *operator()()* can indeed be used instead of *operator<(),* but not quite as you did it.  The *operator<()* is probably easier, anyway.

Good luck.

Comment: Right. `operator()` only makes sense when it's a member of a class, which in this case would be called a *functor*.

Comment: Yeah I've tried that too but still can't seem to get the syntax right so I must not be understanding something correctly.

Comment: The problem here is you can potentially clash with a less than operator defined by another package. I think provided the comparison functor to the container rather than relying on default template parameters to map it to the operator<